# Error Occured when trying to send rpc request(s)

Tags: ethereum, json-rpc

I'm trying to send many simultaneous requests to read the data in Kovan and often I would get the message “Error occurred when trying to send rpc request(s)” or “Rpc timeout after 20000 milliseconds”. I am currently using Infura.

Any ideas of why this is happening or any solutions to this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How many requests are you sending to Infura?

Sending too many requests in a short period of time could cause this error. Try to increase the time span between each request.